# ASM question, two's complement

Tags: nasm

so this book "assembly language step by step" is really awesome, but it was sort of cryptic about how two's complement works when working on actual memory and register data. along with that, i'm not sure how signed values are represented in memory either, which i feel might be what's keeping me confused. anywho...

it says: "-1 = $FF, -2 = $FE and so on". now i understand that the two's complement of a number is itself multiplied by -1 and when added to the original will give you 0. so, FF is the hex equivalent of 11111111 in binary, and 255 in decimal. so my question is: what's the book saying when it says "-1 = $FF"? does it mean that -255 + -1 will give you 0 but also, which it didn't explicitly, set the OF flag?

so in practice... let's say we have 11h, which is 17 in decimal, and 00100001 in binary. and this value is in AL.
so then we NEG AL, and this will set the CF and SF, and change the value in AL to... 239 in decimal, 11101111 in binary, or EFh? i just don't see how that would be 17 * -1? or is that just a poorly worded explanation by the book, where it really means that it gives you the value you would need to cause an overflow?

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In two's complement, for bytes, `(-x)` == `(256 - x)` == `(~x + 1)`.  (`~` is C'ish for the NOT operator, which flips all the bits in its operand.)

Let's say we have 11h.

```
100h - 11h == EFh
(256 - 17  == 239)
```

Note, the 256 works with bytes, cause they're 8 bits in size.  For 16-bit words you'd use 2^16 (65536), for dwords 2^32.  Also note that all math is mod 256 for bytes, 65536 for shorts, etc.

Or, using not/+1,

```
~11h = EEh
+1...  EFh
```

This method works for words of all sizes.

Comment: thanks for the quick responses guys! okay i get it. so now my question is, what does this sort of notation accomplish? why is there both a one's and two's complement?

Comment: Two's complement is common because it makes a very convenient way to represent signed numbers.  `x - y == x + -y`, consistently.  I'm not sure exactly what good one's complement is, other than its use in IP as a checksum (IIRC).

Comment: @zero: My recollection is two's complement is generally used over one's complement because it's slightly simpler in hardware implementation (it needs fewer special cases in hardware logic for subtraction or something). It also has the advantage that there's only one representation for zero (one's complement also has a 'negative zero'). The only drawback to two's complement I can think of is that you get one less positive number that can be represented than negative numbers. For example, a signed char can go down to `-128`, but can only go up to `127`. That negative zero had to go somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

> what's the book saying when it says "-1 = $FF"?

If considering a byte only, the two's complement of `1` is `0xff` (or `$FF` if using that format for hex numbers).

To break it down, the complement (or one's complement) of `1` is `0xfe`, then you add `1` to get the two's complement: `0xff`

Similarly for `2`: the complement is `0xfd`, add `1` to get the two's complement: `0xfe`

Now let's look at 17 decimal.  As you say, that's `0x11`.  The complement is `0xee`, and the two's complement is `0xef` - all that agrees with what you stated in your question.

Now, experiment with what happens when you add the numbers together.  First in decimal:

```
17 + (-17) == 0
```

Now in hex:

```
0x11 + 0xef == 0x100
```

Since we're dealing with numeric objects that are only a byte in size, the `1` in `0x100` is discarded (some hand waving here...), and we result in:

```
0x11 + 0xef == 0x00
```

To deal with the 'hand waving' (I probably won't do this in an understandable manner, unfortunately): since the overflow flag (`OF` or sometimes called `V` for reasons that I don't know) is the same as the carry flag (`C`) the carry can be ignored (it's an indication that signed arithmetic occurred correctly).  One way to think of it that's probably not very precise, but I find useful, is that leading ones in a negative two's complement number are 'the same as' leading zeros in a non-negative two's complement number.